# using list.files to read many shape files and then merge them into one big file

Tags: r

I have more than 1000 shape files in a directory, and I want to select only 10 of them whose names are already known to me as follows:

```
15TVN44102267_Polygons.shp, 15TVN44102275_Polygons.shp
15TVN44102282_Polygons.shp, 15TVN44102290_Polygons.shp
15TVN44102297_Polygons.shp, 15TVN44102305_Polygons.shp
15TVN44102312_Polygons.shp, 15TVN44102320_Polygons.shp
15TVN44102327_Polygons.shp, 15TVN44102335_Polygons.shp
```

First I want to read only these shape files using the list.files command, and then merge them into one big file. I tried the following command, but it failed. I will appreciate any assistance from the community.

```
setwd('D/LiDAR/CHM_tree_objects')
files <- list.files(pattern="15TVN44102267_Polygons|
15TVN44102275_Polygons|    15TVN44102282_Polygons|
15TVN44102290_Polygons|    15TVN44102297_Polygons|
15TVN44102305_Polygons|    15TVN44102312_Polygons|
15TVN44102320_Polygons|    15TVN44102327_Polygons|
15TVN44102335_Polygons|    15TVN44102342_Polygons|
15TVN44102350_Polygons|    15TVN44102357_Polygons",
recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different approach. If you already know the location of the files and their file names, you don't need to use `list.files`:

```
library(sf)

baseDir <- '/temp/r/'
filenames <- c('Denisonia-maculata.shp', 'Denisonia-devisi.shp')
filepaths <- paste(baseDir, filenames, sep='')

# Read each shapefile and return a list of sf objects
listOfShp <- lapply(filepaths, st_read)

# Look to make sure they're all in the same CRS
unique(sapply(listOfShp, st_crs))

# Combine the list of sf objects into a single object
combinedShp <- do.call(what = sf:::rbind.sf, args=listOfShp)
```

`combinedShp` will then be an `sf` object that has all the features in your individual shapefiles. You can then write that out to a single file in your chosen format with `st_write`.

Comment: Hi Stewart, Great! thanks for your help. Your codes work fine to get the combinedShp (i.e., combined sf objects). However, when I try to write that out to a single shapefile using st_write(combinedShp, "combinedshp.shp"), I'm getting the following error: GDAL Error 6: Geometry type of `3D Polygon' not supported in shapefiles. Any clue on what is happening and how to correct it? Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, it works when I use st_write(combinedShp, "combinedShp.gpkg"). But st_write(combinedShp, "combinedShp.shp") does not work

Comment: Glad you got it working. Are your original shapefiles 3D Polygons?

Comment: Yes, the polygons are LiDAR-derived tree objects (i.e., individual tree crown boundaries) produced using FUSION software. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Stewart, I am getting an error "Error: arguments have different crs" when trying to combine more thousand shape files into one big shape file using the following R scripts. Could you plz help me to correct this. Thanks

library(sf)
filepaths <- list.files("D:/tree_objects_by_lidar_tiles/", pattern="*_Polygons.shp$", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
filepaths1<- filepaths[1:1000]
listOfShp <- lapply(filepaths1, st_read)
combinedShp <- do.call(what = sf:::rbind.sf, args=listOfShp)
st_write(obj = combinedShp, dsn = "D:/tree_objects/tree_objects_combined1.gpkg", update = TRUE)

Comment: Sounds like some of your shapefiles have a different CRS. What does `unique(sapply(listOfShp, crs))` tell you? If there are multiple CRSes listed in there, you'll need to figure out which ones are different and what your target CRS is. If you're still having issues, ask another question and leave a link here and I'll try to help out.

Comment: Hi Stewart, all the shape files have same CRS. I tried "mapedit" package and it works when I run combinedShp <- mapedit:::combine_list_of_sf(listOfShp)

Comment: Hi Stewart, all the shape files have same CRS. I tried "mapedit" package and it works when I run 

combinedShp <- mapedit:::combine_list_of_sf(listOfShp)

But when I run the code below, it throws that error

combinedShp <-do.call(what=sf:::rbind.sf, args=listOfShp)

unique(sapply(listOfShp, crs)) gives "Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'crs' not found

Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear you go it working. Sounds like the `sf` package isn't loaded properly.